# How to set ParentActivityOrWindow on Android with Xamarin Prism

Tags: android, xamarin, prism, azure-ad-b2c

I am rewriting my vanilla Xamarin app to use Prism Library.

The current app uses Azure ADB2C for authorisation using [this framework](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native).

Android needs to have its parent window set, which is achieved by adding this code into the MainActivity.cs of the Android project:

```
var authenticationService = DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticationService>();
authenticationService.SetParent(this);
```

This doesn't work for the Prism app, authenticationService is null. For the record, the DependencyService used here is Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.

I also tried the example from the [Prism docs](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dependency-injection/registering-types.html) and put this code into the AndroidInitializer:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry container)
{
    // Register any platform specific implementations
    container.RegisterSingleton<IAuthenticationService, B2CAuthenticationService>("B2CAuthenticationService");
    var authService = Container.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>();

    authService.SetParent(this);
}
```

In this code, Container (which is a DryIoC Container) had no definition for Resolve.

For completeness, this is my App.cs RegisterTypes:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAuthenticationService, B2CAuthenticationService>();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few wrong assumptions you're making here. To start you'll notice that IContainerRegistry specifically has the name Registry in it to imply we don't want you resolving types here. This is why you don't see the Resolve method on it but rather the IContainerProvider instance.

By design, Prism no longer works directly with the Xamarin.Forms DependencyService as this is a complete anti-pattern. That said if you follow the guidance for registering Platform Specific types you can see how to use the IPlatformInitializer to register platform specific types. It is important to realize here that the IPlatformInitializer is called before RegisterTypes is called in PrismApplication.

What I would suggest is to introduce a IParentWindowProvider like:

```
public interface IParentWindowProvider
{
    object Parent { get; }
}
```

You can then implement this on Android like:

```
public class MainActivity : IPlatformInitializer, IParentWindowProvider
{
    object IParentWindowProvider.Parent => this;

    void IPlatformInitializer.RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IParentWindowProvider>(this);
    }
}
```

Then in your Application you might do something like:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    if(Container.IsRegistered<IParentWindowProvider>())
    {
        var provider = Container.Resolve<IParentWindowProvider>();
        var authService = Container.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>();
        authService.SetParent(provider.Parent);
    }
}
```

For more info be sure to check out the relevant docs and sample

- https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dependency-injection/platform-specific-services.html
- https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/03-PlatformSpecificServices

Comment: Thanks Dan. The Container used in OnInitialized doesn't have a definition for IsRegistered. Is there something else to use?

Comment: @DaveSav you can call Container.GetContainer().IsRegistered<T>()

Comment: Yes, that is working, but Container.GetContainer().IsRegistered<IParentWindowProvider>() is false